# HttpServletResponse set charset does not wok in Quarkus/undertow

Tags: spring, servlets, quarkus

I am trying to handle exceptions in a Quarkus based Spring application using the raw Http servlet api.

Source codes: [PostExceptionHandler#handleException2](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/spring-post-service/src/main/java/com/example/PostExceptionHandler.java#L42)

```java
@ExceptionHandler(Exception2.class)
public void handleException2(Exception2 e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    out.write("{\"message\":\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"}");
    out.flush();
}
```

When I ran the application, and access url to test this exception.

```java
@GetMapping("e2")
public ResponseEntity exception2(){
    throw new Exception2("error 2");
}
```

When the exception is caught, it always set charset as **ISO-8859-1**.

```sh
curl -v http://localhost:8080/e2
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /e2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{"message":"Exception 2:error 2"}*
```

I am not sure this is an issue of Undertow or Quarkus.

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sandbox/blob/master/spring-post-service/).

**UPDATE**: fixed the issue by changing the order of codes, for the detailed explanation see [Quarkus#5693](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5693)

```java
response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("{\"message\":\"" + e.getMessage() + "\"}");
        out.flush();
```

Comment: Interesting issue! I'll have a look later and see if this is just an issue with the Spring compatibility or if it also happens with RESTEasy + Undertow

Comment: It indeed seems to be ignored when using RESTEasy + Undertow without any of the Spring stuff

Comment: Can you open an issue please @Hantsy?

Comment: Created issue [#5693](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5693)